# Is it possible to add an integer holding months to a date type in a query and output with AS to have a new column in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm trying to add to the months alone to make a new date then output that in the query with AS but not sure how to do this.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Lease_Agreement`
(
    `ContractID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `StartDate` DATE NOT NULL,
    `Duration` INT NOT NULL,
    `Rent` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    `Live?` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`ContractID`)
);
```

Here is something I was playing with but probably has a lot of issues.

```
SELECT SUM(MONTH(StartDate) + Duration) AS "Total Time of Occupation"
```

This is part of a larger query but for now I just need this

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: John your question is not clear.. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please tell us your date storage format.

Comment: Note that money is rarely float. It's why DECIMAL was invented!

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need a function for this.  MySQL understands interval arithmetic:

```
select startdate + interval duration month
```

Comment: Well, it secretly introduces a function

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can use `date_add()`:

```
 date_add(my_date, interval my_num month) as my_new_date
```

Where `my_date` is of date (or datetime) datatype and `my_num` is an integer.